# Creating a permissioned blockchain on docker

Tags: blockchain, docker

Will he helpful if  anybody can guide be on any documentation on how to create a permissioned blockchain on docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a permissioned blockchain you normally don't want to use proof-of-work, so you don't want to run native Geth. You might be interested in Eris (new name Monax): They provide a permissioned blockchain based on Tendermint, which assumes identifed validators with known public keys. Everything they do is Docker-based out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanx , Yeah i have tried tendermint .  But  i want to use smart contracts . Does Eris support it .

Comment: Yeah it does support

Comment: Yes, Eris uses the EVM, so contracts that work in Ethereum will work in Eris. You can write your contracts in Solidity and they work just the same. The JavaScript libraries you use to talk to it are annoyingly subtly different to the standard Ethereum web3.js, but their equivalent has basically the same functionality.

Comment: Edmund , Is their any way we add add peer . I don't see this functionality in eris

Comment: Yes, you either connect them all to the same bootstrap node or connect them to each other individually. I'm not sure whether you have to do it in the config files or whether you can also do it from the console like Geth.

Answer (score 0):

please check these links :

1- github project to Run a private Ethereum chain with Docker :

https://github.com/stevebakh/docker-ethereum

2-Alpine Linux based docker images for Geth :

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Running-in-Docker